# Azure AD B2C Connected user change password with Graph AD API

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-graph-api

We are using Azure AD B2C and I'm trying to implement the changePassword function for signed-in users. We have followed this tutorial https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-devquickstarts-graph-dotnet, and we have succeeded to make it worked. 
But we want signed-in users to have the possibility to change their existing password (directly in applications). We found this method (https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/azure/ad/graph/api/functions-and-actions#changePassword) but we failed to make it work...

What is the standard workflow for using AD Graph API in AD B2C with signed-in users ? 
I have an application linked to a B2C tenant. I have created both Android and iOS apps and I am able to connect and get tokens thanks to the sign-up or sign-in policy, this point is OK... 
In parallel I have created a service app in order to use the AD Graph API (thanks to the first link above). 
We have suceeded in testing some operations like get the lists of users, find a specific user, change some.... But now I want to use the method "changePassword" for the connected users (second li) and I have failed using it. I don't know which access token to provide, both tests (using the token from the app service credential or using the access token received thanks to the signin policy) have failed ??
Other question, is it normal that the app service I have created with PowerShell is not visible in the Azure Portal ??

Thanks ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Other question, is it normal that the app service I have created with PowerShell is not visible in the Azure Portal ??

We can locate the service principal which created by PowerShell by searching the appPrincipalId like below:

[image]

### Update

To perform the change password REST API of Azure AD Graph, we need to provide the delegate access token. In this scenario, we can use **resource owner password credentials flow** which require users' username and password for the authentication. To use this flow we can register the service principal like below:

```
$app = New-AzureRmADApplication -DisplayName "appPS2" -HomePage "https://adb2cfei.onmicrosoft.com/appPS2" -IdentifierUris "https://adb2cfei.onmicrosoft.com/appPS2" -Password "123"

New-AzureRmADServicePrincipal -ApplicationId $app.ApplicationId
```

Then we need to login the Azure classic portal to grant the delegate permission `Directory.AccessAsUser.All` as figure below:

[image]

Here is the code to acquire the token using the **resource owner password credentials flow**:

```
Post: https://login.microsoftonline.com/adb2cfei.onmicrosoft.com/oauth2/token

resource=https%3a%2f%2fgraph.windows.net&client_id={ $app.ApplicationId}&grant_type=password&username=fx%40adb2cfei.onmicrosoft.com&password={currentPassword}&client_secret=123
```

Then we can use this token to change the password of the sign-in user like below:

```
POST: https://graph.windows.net/adb2cfei.onmicrosoft.com/me/changePassword?api-version=1.6

authorization: bearer {access_token}
content-type: application/json

{
"currentPassword":"{currentPassword}",
"newPassword":"{newPassword}"
}
```

Comment: Ok for the location in the portal.

Comment: But I'm afraid that I don't understand the rest of your answer. Following the tutorial, I've already done the grant update you talk about. And I'm able to do the reset password with the Graph Api (https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/azure/ad/graph/api/users-operations#ResetUserPassword).  But now, if I want to implement the changePassword (for example : https://graph.windows.net/me/changePassword?api-version) for signed-in users, what access token I have to put in the header ? I have tried with the access token from my B2C app and it doesn't work...

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I will update the post, please let me know whether it is helpful.

Comment: Just for more information : it seems that we need the "userPrincipalName" in the username parameter. Is it possible to get this information in the claims returned by the AD B2C policies (sign-in or sign-up) ? or do I have to get this information in a first step with the Graph API ?

Comment: At present, we are not able to get the `upn` from the id_token return to the application. You can find all the support claims for the Azure AD B2C from [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-reference-tokens). As a workaround, the application may require users enter both username and password. And if you want the Azure AD B2C to support issue `upn` claim, you may submit the feedback from [here](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/34192--general-feedback).

Comment: So what I have to do is : first call the Graph API in order to get the json with all the user information. Retrieve the upn in the json and use it with the current pwd to acquire the token and then call the changePassword method  ?

Comment: You were not able to call the Graph API since there is no access token you can get. To update the users' password, the users need to provide both the username and current password.

Comment: Sorry but not sure I understand what you said. My actual process which permit me to accomplish the change pwd as a connected AD B2C user : 1. get a token for the GRAPH API (thanks to the appID and appSecret). 2. request the user info with the user objectID with the token I get in the first step. 3. Parse the json and retrieve the UPN in it. 4. request a token for the app service you describe in your first answer with : the UPN and the current password. 5. Call the graph changepassword with the json you describe (old & new pwd) and the token (step 4) in the header. Is there a shorter process ?

Comment: @user1523812 No. I don't think there is any step we can skip.