# Registering a service application in an Azure B2C Active Directory using PowerShell

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-ad-b2c

I'm following [this guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-devquickstarts-graph-dotnet) to create an application in my Azure B2C active directory.

I have created a new local user called `admin@{mytenant}.onmicrosoft.com` which is set as a global user. I am using this user to manage my active directory with PowerShell.

It seems that the application (service principal) gets created successfully. There are no errors returned and when I run `Get-MsolServicePrincipal` the newly created app appears in the list.

However it is nowhere to be found in the old Azure portal (http://manage.windowsazure.com) nor the new one (http://portal.azure.com). Am I doing something wrongly with creating it?

Answer (score 0):

The answer of the question below could be useful for you : [Azure AD B2C Connected user change password with Graph AD API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41549492/azure-ad-b2c-connected-user-change-password-with-graph-ad-api)

I don't know if it's possible in the old portal.